# PhpSpreadsheet -missing styling

Tags: php, styling, phpspreadsheet

I have a hard time styling my table using PhpSpreadsheet. The table displays fine with all data intact, but no styling.

```
require 'vendor/autoload.php';
use PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Spreadsheet;
$inputFileName = 'upload/test.xlsx';

$inputFileType = \PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\IOFactory::identify($inputFileName);
$reader = \PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\IOFactory::createReader($inputFileType);
$spreadsheet = $reader->load($inputFileName);
$worksheet = $spreadsheet->getActiveSheet();

$styleArray = [
    'borders' => [
        'outline' => [
            'borderStyle' => \PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Style\Border::BORDER_THICK,
            'color' => ['argb' => 'FFFF0000'],
        ],
    ],
];

$worksheet->getStyle('A1:F1')->applyFromArray($styleArray);
```

Displaying the table to the page like this:

```
<div class="container">
    <?php 
        echo '<table class="table table-bordered">' . PHP_EOL;
        foreach ($worksheet->getRowIterator() as $row) {
        echo '<tr>' . PHP_EOL;
        $cellIterator = $row->getCellIterator();
        $cellIterator->setIterateOnlyExistingCells(FALSE); 
            foreach ($cellIterator as $cell) {
                echo '<td>' . $cell->getValue() . '</td>' . PHP_EOL;
            }
        echo '</tr>' . PHP_EOL;
        }
        echo '</table>' . PHP_EOL;
    ?>
</div>
```

No errors in inspect mode (Brave), all files present, nothing missing. Could use Bootstrap to style the table, but really want to get this working. Also I would like to sort the rows based on column value, but that one doesn't work either. If I could get styling working I thing I have a better shot at getting rows sorted.

Thinking there's something wrong in the code or the dependant files/paths, but I have no idea where. PhpSpreadsheet installed with composer, nothing changed or altered.

Just for testing, I can remove rows using:

```
$spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()->removeRow(1, 1);
```

-So something is working ok.